# How to toggle between two different boolean variable in c#

Tags: c#

I have this two different `bool` variable 
`IsAboutToDone` and `IsFinished`

I want to toggle these two `Booleans` using only one key pressed.

For example, 
when I pressed first `Key (V Letter)`
then `IsAboutToDone` should be `true`, then another pressed `IsAboutToDone` should be `false`, then if I press Again same letter then `IsFinished` should be `true` and pressing onemore time would be `isFinished` = `false`

Basically 
I am looking something like this solution which can be done like

`IsAboutToDone =! IsAboutToDone`

but using two different `Booleans` variable.

Can anyone give me advice, what approach would be best.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the example you gave. Perhaps you could go into more detail about how you actually intend to use this functionality?

Comment: You have a tri-state variable.  Use an enum instead of a boolean.

Comment: I am looking if possible to use same key pressed letter to toggle between two different Boolean variable.  Right now, I have made two different keyboard Letter to toogle these two different boolean. So I am looking if possible to make toogling with only one keyboard letter.

Answer (score 2):

Logically shortest:

```
IsFinished = IsAboutToDone;
IsAboutToDone = !(IsAboutToDone || IsFinished);
```

However if other people will read your code, it could be easier to understand if you use an enum for this, and implement an if-else or a switch block.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totaly sure to understand your need.

With

```
IsAboutToDone = !IsAboutToDone && IsFinished
IsFinished = !IsFinished && IsAboutToDone
```

if IsAboutToDone is False , it will be True if Finished is not True

if IsFinished is False , it will be True if IsAboutToDone is True

That match your example

Edit : Agree with t.m. a enum will be probably more understandable

Answer (score 0):

You may save the last pressed key into a variable and while using keyPressEvent change the states of the variable you have by checking the last saved value.

Comment: In Global Declare a variable to save the last pressed value for example int lastPressed = 0;
In "KeyPressEvent" function you can store the pressed key value in the form of an integer such as
int value = PressedKey.Value;
if(value==lastPressed)
{
IsAboutToDone = false;
}
else
{
IsAboutToDone = true;
}